# Only the last row is inserted to my sql database from a text file after splitting it with PYTHON

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, text-files

Below is my code for splitting a text file with a pipe as the delimiter and inserting it to the database . The problem is only the last row is inserted to my database but it reads the whole text file. Meaning, my text file have 34 entries and when I run the program, I get 34 rows with same data, which is the last row.

Sample of the text file content:

> 4 | kenichi | matsuyama | 02498
>   5 | toru | watanabe | 92832

The last row is 5 | toru | watanabe | 92832 and when I run it, I got 34 rows of this data.. 
There are no errors, only that the last row is the only data inserted to my sql database. Thank you for the help and I understand if others will get upset the way I code. I am still learning this stuff.

what i want is to load all the rows from my text file to my table. Thanks!

```
import csv 
import pymssql

db = pymssql.connect(host='localhost', user='xx', password='xx', database='dbpython')
cursor = db.cursor()

filename = "ttest.txt"

mynumbers = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        mynumbers.append([n for n in line.strip().split(' | ')])
    for pair in mynumbers:
        try:
            x,y,z,a = pair[0],pair[1],pair[2],pair[3]
        except IndexError:
            print "A line in the file doesn't have enough entries."

print "Records stored in a variable"

cursor.execute('truncate table tbl_contact')
with open('ttest.txt') as f:
    for row in f:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tbl_contact VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', (x,y,z,a))
    print "Record Inserted"

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing only the last x,y,z,a assignments to the table. Try this:

```
import csv 
import pymssql

db = pymssql.connect(host='localhost', user='xx', password='xx', database='dbpython')
cursor = db.cursor()

filename = "ttest.txt"
mynumbers = []

cursor.execute('truncate table tbl_contact')

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         try:
             values = line.strip().split('|')
             x,y,z,a = int(values[0]), values[1], values[2], values[3]
             cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tbl_contact VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', (x,y,z,a))
             print "Record Inserted"
         except IndexError:
             print "Some error occurred."

db.commit()
db.close()
```

You also don't need the list comprehension and brackets here:

```
[n for n in line.strip().split(' | ')]
```

You can do this instead:

```
line.strip().split(' | ')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @kennes913. I tried the code but there were errors. I forgot to mention that the first column have a integer type.     This is the error:

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO tbl_contact VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)', (x,y,z,a))
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 465, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:7190)
OperationalError: (245, "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'fid' to data type int.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

Comment: already fixed the error. The error was: **Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'fid' to data type int**. I changed the data type in my table int to varchar and it worked! Thank you for the help :)